# JS Function will not .show() div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am calling a `function` from a different function. I have a `console.log("test");` to make sure that my nested function is actually being called, and it is. The `inputs2` is not `writing` the text I input.

Here is my external JS

```
function iOwners (tempOwnersName) {
    // write to div: indirowners

    console.log("Test");

    $("#ioi").show();

    var inputs2 = $('#inputs2').empty();

    $("#inputs2").show();


    $('#inputs2').append('<p>Owners of ' + tempOwnersName + '</p><br/><br/><form id="div3">Owner Name: <input type="text" id="indirectExecutivesName" name="indirectExecutivesName"/><br/>Owner Customer Number: <input type="text" id="indirectExecutivesECN" name="indirectExecutivesECN" /><br/>Does the Owner have Control over the Entity: Yes: <input type="radio" name="indirectExecutivesControl" value="yes" /> or No: <input type="radio" name="indirectExecutivesControl" value="no" /><br/>What Percent (do not use % symbol) does the Owner own: <input type="text" name="indirectExecutivesPercent" /></form><br/><br/>');

}
```

The portion of my HTML that applies:

```
<div id="inputs2"></div>
<button id="ioi" onclick="return false">Submit</button>
```

My CSS file that applies:

```
#ioi {
    display: none;
}
#inputs2 {
    display: none;
}
```

My show/hide functions work on many other pieces, but not inputs2 (inputs2 works in other functions as well, that's why I empty it)

Comment: `inputs2.innerHTML` isn't valid. `inputs2` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element. There's also no need to do that since you already did `$("#inputs2").empty()`.

Comment: There's nothing in `indirowners`, what is it supposed to show?

Comment: and what is i variable should be?

Comment: The ID in the HTML is `indirownersdisp`, but the Javascript and CSS are using `#indirowners`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ugz3swL/

Comment: It works when I add a value for `i`: http://jsfiddle.net/6xjdyzdj/4/

Comment: if you're getting the `console.log("test")` then obviously it's hitting. your console doesn't show errors?

Comment: @RobScott exactly..  I removed all reference to `i` because that was a stupid copy/paste mistake on my side.. it's still not showing `inputs2`   **updated question**

Comment: ok - figured it out. When it returned back to it's calling function, there is a `var inputs2 = $('#inputs2').empty();` so it's clearing it before I have a chance to input anything. I moved it to after the next button click - thanks everyone for helping me clean this up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work with no modification

```js
function iOwners (tempOwnersName) {
    // write to div: indirowners

    console.log("Test");

    $("#ioi").show();

    var inputs2 = $('#inputs2').empty();

    $("#inputs2").show();


    $('#inputs2').append('<p>Owners of ' + tempOwnersName + '</p><br/><br/><form id="div3">Owner Name: <input type="text" id="indirectExecutivesName" name="indirectExecutivesName"/><br/>Owner Customer Number: <input type="text" id="indirectExecutivesECN" name="indirectExecutivesECN" /><br/>Does the Owner have Control over the Entity: Yes: <input type="radio" name="indirectExecutivesControl" value="yes" /> or No: <input type="radio" name="indirectExecutivesControl" value="no" /><br/>What Percent (do not use % symbol) does the Owner own: <input type="text" name="indirectExecutivesPercent" /></form><br/><br/>');

}

iOwners('Hello Kity');
```

```css
#ioi {
    display: none;
}
#inputs2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs2"></div>
<button id="ioi" onclick="return false">Submit</button>
```